# SSRS report being delivered to non-subscriber

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

Some users are receiving delivery of SSRS reports to which they are no longer subscribed

Verified users are not listed in TO or CC or BCC

Expect the obvious non-delivery to non-subscribers

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any hidden reports with subscriptions that have been set and forgotten about? Have a look at the logs to see which report sent out what. There has to be a logical reason! Is this a standard or data driven subscription?

Comment: Are there any DISTRIBUTION LISTS in the e-mail addresses that may have the user? i.e. `DEPT@GIANTCORP.COM` Is there something triggering a subscription (does the Last Run match the report schedule)? I have reports with a subscription that are triggered by an SSIS job - the schedule ended 2 years ago.

Comment: No distribution lists would account for it.  The subscription is standard vs data driven.  I will check the execution log.  The problem seems to have resolved itself.  Harry, as you said, there has to be a logical reason.  Gremlins doesn't cut it.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem has magically resolved itself without my being able to provide an explanation.  As dissatisfying an example of "GREMLINS" is, I cannot come up with anything else.  I appreciate the suggestions for solutions to a problem that on its surface seems nonsensical.